# Use Numpad as arrow keys

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, numpad

I'm used to use numeric pad as arrow keys when numpad is off in windows. May I have same behaviour in ubuntu 14.04?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,of course. Switch off Num Lock and use them!

Comment: I assume you meant Ubuntu 14.04,right? Yet there must be no difference.

Comment: Yes, it is 14.04. I edited the answer. Sorry but it doesn't work when I switch off Num Lock. 8,2,4 and 6 doesn't move the cursor.

Comment: Ok, I found the issue. This is not an ubuntu related problem but IntelliJ editor. Did not tried outside the code editor.

Comment: Does this also simply work in recent Ubuntu versions such as 20.04? doesn't seem to happen for me :-\